# Textbox in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview which contains a textbox and a save button.
When i press the save button an event is triggered. How do i get the text from the textbox in the code behind so i can save it in a database?
I must add the Text in the CommandArgument of the button, but i don't know how.

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#TextBox1.Text????????? %>'>save</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you will need to get textbox and it's value on button click:

```
1: <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" onitemcommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">

2:  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Save">Save</asp:LinkButton> 

3:   
    protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Save")
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1");
                string x = tb.Text;
            }
        }
```

But just wondering why you want a textbox in the itemtemplate? Is that all of your listview or it is just for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the ItemCommand handler.   See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx

Check ListViewCommandEvent too - it will give you information you need ...

Another thing, in your markup, set your buttons' `CommandArgument` property to a string: e.g `Save', 'Edit', 'Delete'.

Then in your eventhandler you can check this so you know whether Save, Edit or Delete.